# Использование метода как параметра другого метода

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, функции, return

Уважаемые коллеги, нужна ваша помощь. Я хочу при помощи метода `Limits`, выставлять лимит. Параметром метода я использую метод `Total_amount`, но у меня выводится значение `x=1000`, хотя мне необходимо чтобы выводилось значение `1017` - это сумма параметров двух объектов.

При выводе print в методе `Total_amount` выводится значение `1017`, а когда ставлю `return` - то выводится значение `1000`.

```
class Cash_Calculator():
    c = []
    #d = dt.date.today()
    def __init__(self, a, b, limit=1000):  # Сразу ставл лимит
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = int(b)
        self.limit = limit
    def pluss(self):
        sum = self.a + self.b
        return sum
    def minus(self):
        difference = self.a - self.b
        return difference
    def add_record(self):
        # иницирую добавление записей в список "c"
        if self.pluss() !=None:
            return Cash_Calculator.c.append(self.pluss())
        elif self.minus() !=None:
            return Cash_Calculator.c.append(self.minus())
    def total_amount(self):
        #прохожу по списку и складываю значения на выходе: x = 1017
        x = 0
        for i in Cash_Calculator.c:
            if i == None:
                break
            x += i
            return x
            
    def limits(self, sum_amount): 
        x = sum_amount  #параметр sum_amount - это функция total_amount
            #x = int(sum_amount)
            #if self.limit >= x:
                #print("Вы можете еще потратить!")
            #else:
                #print("Ваш Лимит исчерпан")
        print(x)

C = Cash_Calculator(993,7)
C.pluss()
C.add_record()
C.total_amount()
C.limits(C.total_amount())

C1 = Cash_Calculator(10,7)
C1.pluss()
C1.add_record()
C1.total_amount()
C1.limits(C1.total_amount())
```

Результат:
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\MSI\Documents\GitHub\hw_python_oop> & C:/Users/MSI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/MSI/Documents/GitHub/hw_python_oop/small test.py"
1000
1000
PS C:\Users\MSI\Documents\GitHub\hw_python_oop>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в методе `total_amount()` - `return x` сдвинут.

```
class Cash_Calculator():
    c = []
    
    def __init__(self, a, b, limit=1000):   
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = int(b)
        self.limit = limit
        
    def pluss(self):
        sum = self.a + self.b
        return sum
        
    def minus(self):
        difference = self.a - self.b
        return difference
        
    def add_record(self):
        # иницирую добавление записей в список "c"
        if self.pluss():                               # ? !=None:
            return self.c.append(self.pluss())
        elif self.minus():                             # ? !=None:
            return self.c.append(self.minus())
            
    def total_amount(self):
        x = 0
        for i in self.c:
# ?           if i == None:
# ?                break
            x += i
#            return x                                   # <----
        return x                                        # +++
            
    def limits(self, sum_amount): 
        x = sum_amount         
        print(x)


C = Cash_Calculator(993, 7)
_pluss = C.pluss()
_c = C.add_record()
_x = C.total_amount()
_limits = C.limits(C.total_amount())
print('-' * 30)

C1 = Cash_Calculator(10, 7)
_pluss = C1.pluss()
_c = C1.add_record()
_x = C1.total_amount()
_limits = C1.limits(C1.total_amount())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам, а то уже не знал, что делать.

Comment: @АндрейКривошеин Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Благодарю Вас, поставил флаг. Извините, сразу не заметил.